# Passing input value via button click to php function in script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to use the value from an input field - without a POST - to do a lookup from an external source.

The input field has a button associated with it, which calls the script on button press. So I need to put the input field (id = 'lookup') into the function's parameter (the function is called within the script).

This is the code line in the script that needs the value from the input field (input field called 'lookup')

```
<?php $product_name = api_request(lookup);?>
```

My code is below.

(NB: I know about 'PHP is server side, JS is client site'. But the button click **does** call the PHP function, and the code does display the return value of the function if you do this instead:

```
<?php $product_name = api_request('1234');?>
```

which will return "My Product Name" via my `api_request()` function.)

What is needed to put a script variable in the `api_request()`'s parameter?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<p>Part Number = <input type="text" id="lookup" value= "12345"></p>
<button>Get product name for this part number</button>
<div id='product_name'>Product Name Goes Here </div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){ 
        // returns value of input field 
        var lookup = document.getElementById('lookup'); 
        // need to put the input field 'lookup' into the function's parameter
        <?php $product_name = api_request(lookup);?>
        var product_name = "<?php echo $product_name; ?>";
    $('#product_name').text(product_name); // display it on the screen in that div ID

    });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
<?php 

function api_request($partnumber) {
    // code that returns the product name for that part number, hard coded here
    $product_name = "My Product Name";
return $product_name;
}
```

Comment: When you put a constant into the call e.g. `api_request('1234')` the value can be (and *is*) evaluated when the page loads. It is not being evaluated when you click the button. Take a look at your page source and you will see `var product_name = <some constant value>` already in the text. You can only access PHP functions after page load via an ajax call or the like.

Answer (score 0):

As you already understand PHP is server and JS is client, you cannot directly use JS variables in PHP.

There are two ways by which you can.

1. $_POST which you already said you don't want to use. I assume the reason for not using $_POST is that browser prompts to continue refreshing page.
2. Use $_GET which will add a param in your url.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="get">
<p>Part Number = <input type="text" id="lookup" name="lookup" value= "12345"></p>
<button>Get product name for this part number</button>
</form>
```

Additionally add this small line in the beginning of your file to access is as a PHP variable.

```
$lookup = $_GET["lookup"];
```

Comment: Note that the question states that there is no POST of the input field, which is not in a FORM tag. Only the click of the button 'submits' the form.  So it is my understanding there is no POST or GET value to be used.
The input field value needs to be sent as a parameter of the apirequest() function.

Comment: Again since PHP is a server code it need the value from client to be passed to server. $_GET and $_POST are ways by which you can send the data back to the PHP code. Another way is to make an endpoint to execute a PHP code which would be even more complex.

Comment: -   Perhaps setting a cookie with jquery, and then using the $_COOKIE in the php code inside the jquery function? I've searched around and have found varying ways to set a cookie with jquery, but none have worked. And I need to allow for non-cookie-allowed visitors. So - perhaps a way to set a PHP session variable within the jquery function?

Comment: You cannot perform PHP operations using jQuery. It has to be a server call.

Comment: Actually, the above code works if you put any value (string) in the $product_name = api_request("xxxx"); (at least it did  the last time I tested it. And if I create a cookie in JS, then use the cookie in the PHP function, it seems to work, although not consistently. In either case, it seems that I can call the php function within the script code.

Comment: Cookies when set would be sent for each server call, so it is not recommended to use cookies for passing variables to php function that is this page specific.

Comment: are you talking about the api_request() in you question ? 
If yes, it worked because you are returning a string which is hard coded. Also api_request itself is php code and it would run on the server not with jQuery code.

Answer (score 0):

ajax is possible.

try this

create file : api_request.php

```
<?php 
function api_request($partnumber) {
// code that returns the product name for that part number, hard coded here
$product_name = "My Product Name";
return $product_name;
}
$number = $_GET["part"];
$product_name = api_request($number);
echo json_encode(array( "product_name" => $product_name ));
```

And Modify the javascript with this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){ 
    // returns value of input field 
    var lookup = document.getElementById('lookup'); 
    // need to put the input field 'lookup' into the function's parameter
    $.get(`api_request.php?part=${ lookup.value }`,(resp)=>{
$('#product_name').text(resp.product_name); // display it on the screen in that 
},"json");

});
```

});

Comment: The issue is not with the api_request function being called  - that works just fine- but with supplying the 'lookup' value (the value of the input field) to the api_request function as a function parameter. Note that there is no form that is used by the input field, so (I think) there is no $_GET or $_POST value to use.